# How to compress a file (gzip) using boost libraries in C++

Tags: boost, compression, gzip, iostream

Im trying to compress a file using boost library (gzip).
Its a simple task: lets suppose i have the file **data.xml** and I need to compress it to **data.xml.gz**. I can even use the default compression values, doesn't matter.

I tryed to look up in google and BOOST pages but with no success.

I have the following:

```
bool SyncFrequencyHistory::frequencyHistoryCompressFile(void)
{
    printf("\r\n===== ACTION: frequencyHistoryCompressFile =====\r\n");

    std::ifstream inStream(FREQUENCY_HISTORY_FILE, std::ios_base::in);
    std::ofstream outStream(FREQUENCY_HISTORY_FILE_GZIP, std::ios_base::out);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::output> out;
    out.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    out.push(outStream);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, out);

    return true;
}
```

FREQUENCY_HISTORY_FILE have the full location of the XML file

FREQUENCY_HISTORY_FILE_GZIP have the full location for the XML.GZ file

I know almost all code is wrong, but i have no idea who to write it the correct way.

Comment: Is running gzip as an external command not an option?

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already solved it! I changed to ZLIB library.

```
#include <zlib.h>

(...)

gzFile fi = gzopen(FILENAME,"wb");
gzprintf(fi,"This is a string"\r\n");
gzclose(fi);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the following [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/wiki/TutorialsBoostIOstreams), I believe your code should be:

```
bool SyncFrequencyHistory::frequencyHistoryCompressFile(void)
{
    printf("\r\n===== ACTION: frequencyHistoryCompressFile =====\r\n");

    std::ifstream inStream(FREQUENCY_HISTORY_FILE, std::ios_base::in);
    std::ofstream outStream(FREQUENCY_HISTORY_FILE_GZIP, std::ios_base::out);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf< boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push( boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    in.push( inStream );
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, outStream);

    return true;
}
```

Basically, you read the input, compress it and saves the dat

Comment: Thanks! Im going to try it :)

Comment: This code will create a zip file with data compressed, not as file compressed.

Answer (score 1):

This code works, you just need to specify binary type for the output stream: `std::ios_base::binary`.