# compress multiple files into single file in c++

Tags: c++, boost, php-ziparchive, boost-iostreams

I searched through the web to find out if there is any effective way to compress multiple files into one single file using either standard library or boost library. the goal is only compression of files, since decompression could be done manually.

Currently I am using ZipArchive library, but I want to use standard libraries or boost library.
Any help would be appreciated in advance.

**EDIT**
Since it seems that there is no way to compress multiple files into a single file in C++ using standard library, I am wondering what is the best suitable external library to do so. 
I have to mention that I only need to compress files, decompression of them would be done manually.

Comment: The standard library doesn't come with compression features, and I doubt that boost has them either.

Comment: @PlasmaHH thanks, do you have any suggestion? any other external library?

Comment: that would be offtopic here, and besides that you have not stated any requirements, and there are dozens of compression libraries out there that may or may not fit a certain set of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at - [How to compress a file (gzip) using boost libraries in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449670/how-to-compress-a-file-gzip-using-boost-libraries-in-c)

Looks like boost has at least 3 types of compression filters:

- [zlib](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html)
- [gzip](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html)
- [bzip2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/bzip2.html)

Comment: thanks, not "a" file, I need a library to compress multiple files.